# asymptotic bound on Galton-Watson extinction probability

Tags: probability, analysis

Consider a Galton-Watson process with offspring distribution
$$Z \sim \text{Binomial}(d,1-e^{-\lambda/d})$$
with $d$ a large integer and $\lambda >0$. Let $\zeta= \zeta(\lambda)$ be the probability of extinction. We would like to prove that $\zeta \leq e^{-\lambda + \epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon >0$ so long as $\lambda$ is large enough.

This seems true since, classically, we know that $\zeta$ is the unique solution to
$$\zeta = \mathbf E[\zeta^Z] = (e^{-\lambda/d} + (1-e^{-\lambda/d})\zeta)^d.$$
So we can write
$$\zeta^{1/d} - (1- e^{-\lambda/d})\zeta = e^{-\lambda/d}.$$
Plugging in $e^{-\lambda}$ for $\zeta$ is almost a root, since the left side is
$$e^{-\lambda/d} - (1- e^{-\lambda/d} )e^{-\lambda}$$
which is $O(e^{-\lambda})$ away from $e^{-\lambda/d}$. Is there a rigorous way to reason that $\zeta \leq e^{-\lambda + \epsilon}$ for $\lambda$ large enough?

Comment: $\zeta^{1/d} - (1-e^{-\lambda/d}) \zeta$ (as a function of $\zeta$) should have just one local maximum, and the smallest $\zeta$ such that the function equals $e^{-\lambda / d}$ will be than the maximizer. However, I'm not sure if that bound would be tight enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z_i$ be iid copies of $Z$ and $W$ the total progeny. The "hitting time" theorem says that for $t \geq 1$
$$P(W=t) = \frac 1 t P(Z_1+\cdots+Z_t = t-1).$$
Since the $Z_i$ are Binomial random variables, we have $Z_1+\cdots+Z_t \sim \text{Bin}(td,1- e^{-\lambda/d}).$
So,
$$P(W=t) = \frac 1 t \binom{td}{t-1} e^{-\lambda(td - t+1)/d}(1- e^{-\lambda/d})^{t-1}.$$
Using the bound $\binom{td}{t-1} \leq (e t d/(t-1))^{t-1}$ and the fact that $1- e^{-\lambda/d}\leq 1$ (as well as ignoring the $+1$ in the middle term), we then have
$$P(W=t) \leq \frac 1 t \left(\frac{e t d}{t-1}\right)^{t-1} e^{-\lambda t \frac{d-1}{d}} \leq e^{t(1+\log d) - \lambda t\frac{d-1}{d}}\leq e^{-(\lambda - \epsilon)t}$$
given $\epsilon >0$ for $\lambda$ large.
Computing $P(W=0)$ directly, and then summing with this bound gives
$$P(W<\infty) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty P(W=t) \leq \sum_{t=0}^\infty e^{-(\lambda - \epsilon) t} = O(e^{-\lambda + \epsilon}).$$